# Unicorn + Nginx Rails production error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/01/deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3/) to deploy a RoR app with Capistrano but I'm getting an error in my production server

```
[error] 28314#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock:/", host: "myapp.cloudapp.azure.com"
```

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

  listen 3000;
  server_name localhost;

  root /home/deploy/apps/myapp/current/;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I changed the `server` to many different things, but I get the exact same error, with the same host, server, upstream.

The problem was with Unicorn, somewhere in my Capistrano deploy, it wasn't restarting Unicorn as it should.

Comment: Please check that the capistrano and unicorn creates this `/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock` file as it should be created during deploy.

Comment: The only difference between my configurations and this is that I don't use the same name for the upstream. Can you confirm if it works by changing **upstream app** to **upstream mysite** and **proxy_pass http://app;** to **proxy_pass http://mysite;**

Comment: mixan946 it creates

robzdc I changed but still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx logs indicate that this is an issue with the backend server. After your backend up is up and running. Check:

- Does the socket file exist? `ls -lthd /tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock`
- [Can you make a direct HTTP connect to the socket, bypassing Nginx?](https://superuser.com/questions/834307/can-curl-send-requests-to-sockets)

Once those tests pass, test again through Nginx.

Comment: the first one passes, the second one gives an Connection refused

Comment: @tvieira if unicorn can't be accessed directly, focus on on solving that problem and add Nginx back to the mix once the backend app is confirmed to be running properly.

Comment: As it turns out the problem was in Unicorn itself, Nginx was OK.

Comment: @tvieira if my answer led to the fix could you accept it? Also, posting the actual root cause could help others who find this question and answer.